# Marking results in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

I have a query with multiple ORs in the where.

The problem I am having is marking the rows in the result so I can know where each result came from.

For example:
        `select * from people where age>10 or weight>100 or status in ('active','paying','dead')`

So this will return a list of people.

When iterating over that list of people in the result I need to know why that specific person is in the resultset.
So if I could "tag" or "mark" each result with a reason, I could do something like:

`if (person.reason=="age") then do something...`

and

`if (person.reason=="active") then do something else...`

I don't want to duplicate the logic from the query again when iterating over the result (the query is built dynamically and can get quite complicated).

Is this possible?
(BTW I'm doing this in PHP using Doctrine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return a column with the reason in it by using CASE-logic.

Like so:

```
select 
    CASE 
        WHEN age>10 THEN 'age' 
        WHEN weight>100 THEN 'weight' 
        ELSE 'status' 
    END CASE 
    ,* 
from people where age>10 or weight>100 or status in ('active','paying','dead')
```

I am used to MSSQL but the syntax is pretty much the same. Check this page for reference:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Comment: That seems to work. I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way of doing this, this way the logic needs be run twice (in both the select and the where). Maybe something like adding another "virtual" column and "marking" each result in that column somehow in the where clause?

Comment: Well. You could create a computed column in the table with the same logic. That way you wouldn't have to write the logic twice. I would advise you not to implement this though. With computed columns you have the choice of making them persistent. If you do the logic would be run at insert/update and in your case that would acctually work. But consider this scenario: if you change the select query to calculate age from a birthdate - then the row would not have to be updated to fit the select-logic and therefore the persisted computed column wouldn't be updated.

Comment: And if not making it persistent the logic would be run at every Select.

Comment: It cannot be persistent since it needs to be computed at run time and is different for every user. The question is can it be written in a way so that the logic isn't run twice.

Comment: Not really... For starters: a computed column would indeed be different for each user (even if persisted). Anyway; You could use the case-logic without an ELSE-part. That way all rows would return NULL if they don't fit any of the CASE:es. You could then use your query as a derived table and do a WHERE x IS NOT NULL. I am not sure however how the mysql query optimizer would handle this and you could end up with a query that is a lot slower. Keep in mind that the query optimizer will try to find the best plan for your query and I am not sure it will actually execute the logic twice.